# datewise multiple record display

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Hi i have a class called ChatMessageBO which has properties such as Id, Msg, Name, and date.

i want to display data datewise.

```
List<chatmessagebo> SortedList = directChatWindow.messages.OrderBy(o => o.ts).ToList();
MessageList.DataSource = SortedList; 
MessageList.DataBind();
```

here i get all data properly but i want to display date and then name and msg.

example

03-07-2017

jaydeeep hello
rishi hi

04-07-2017

neha god mornin
jaydeep good moring all

view side code
date (Here i required help) 03-june contain 3 records so date then name,msg then 04 june contain 4 msg .

```
'<%#Eval("name")%><%#Eval("msg")%>'
```

Comment: What kind of control 'MessageList` is? Is it a ListView, DataList, GridView, ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the message objects coming from the database by the date. `GroupBy` method of LINQ should be useful.

Next thing you need to do is to use appropriate controls to display grouped data.
Consider following Example.

I have class `ChatMessage` and `MessageGroup`. `ChatMessage` is a simple class as yours with Id, Name, Message and Date properties. `MessageGroup` represents group of messages with Date as Grouping factor.

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class MessageGroup
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public List<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

I am using `asp:DataList` control here to display messages.

```
<asp:DataList ID="messageList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="messageList_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--Displaying date first -->
                    <span><%# Eval("Date") %></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- Inner DataList to display grouped messages-->
                    <asp:DataList ID="subMessageList" runat ="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <span><%# Eval("Name") %> : <%# Eval("Message") %></span>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Following is the approach to group the messages by Date and create List of `MessageGroup` objects and binding it to the datalist.

```
private void DisplayMessages()
{
    var messages = directChatWindow.messages.OrderBy(o => o.ts).ToList();

    var list = messages.GroupBy(msg => msg.Date).Select(grp => new MessageGroup { Date = grp.Key, Messages = grp.ToList() });

    messageList.DataSource = list;
    messageList.DataBind();
}
```

Calling this method in the page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DisplayMessages();
    }
}
```

This code will display only dates in the DataList. To display messages in the inner datalist we need to handle the `ItemDataBound` event of the main datalist.
In this event we will get the current DataItem bound to the current Item of the DataList. This DataItem is an object of `MessageGroup`. We will bind inner DataList to the `Messages` property of the `MessageGroup` instance.

```
protected void messageList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    var messageGroup = e.Item.DataItem as MessageGroup;

    if(messageGroup != null)
    {
        var subList = e.Item.FindControl("subMessageList") as DataList;

        if(subList != null)
        {
            subList.DataSource = messageGroup.Messages;
            subList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can display the data the way you wanted.